# vue router always takes me back to login

Tags: vue.js, react-router

I'd like to use a route guard to check localstorage if the user has the rights to login or not (simple boolean true or false for testing).
If I log in, the router always takes me back to my login, even if the localstoreage says it's authenticated.
If I then click on my logo (`/`), I come to the user area and all works fine.

```
Router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const isAuthed = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("store"));

  if (to.path !== "/login" && isAuthed === null) {
    next("/login");
  } else if (to.path !== "/login" && isAuthed.auth === false) {
    next("/login");
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

These are my routes:

```
const routes = [
  { path: "", name: "Home", component: () => import("pages/Home") },
  { path: "/login", name: "Login", component: () => import("pages/Login") },
  { path: "*", component: () => import("pages/Error404.vue") },
];
export default routes
```

This is my login function to toggle true/false on login and then push the user to home:

```
login: function () {
  store.auth = true
  this.$router.push('/')
}
```

What am I thinking wrong here?

I thought because on the first visit, localstorage is null because it will be set after login, so I added a check if object is null but it's the same.

thanks

Comment: Did you debug localstorage? It's not confirmed that `getItem('store')` is set. Also it's unclear why auth flag was called `store`, could be a mistake.

Comment: I check if the store is there, if not redirect to login, I check if there is a store with auth false and redirect to login. The store is working.

Comment: It's not shown how localstorage is updated. If this is done asynchronously, it should be awaited before redirecting to /.

Comment: you so right, thanks I missed a async login and then push to new route, thats did it.